# scrolling through a virtual list with protractor

Tags: angular, list, protractor, virtual

I know this library is coming up in Angular 6, but I need to implement it in Protractor tests, testing an Angular 5 app.

In the virtual list, there are 10 items displayed at a time. The more more we scroll down, the bottom of the list populates new items (2-3 at a time) and the top of the list depopulates. The item we are looking for can be ex: item 20 on the list, if we do not find it in the current view, I need the test to scroll down until it is found.

The challenge right now is this: when the item is found, line 4 and 5 work well and scroll to the list item. When it is not found, line 4 fails because listItemWeWant.isDisplayed() is false and does not proceed. 
Perhaps there is a better check here, maybe it can be checked if there is anything in the element array finder, or count() can be used. Neither of which I could get to work.

If we can solve this issue, then we will have virtual scrolling tests prior to Angular 6 coming up.

```js
waitUntilScrolledToSelectorInAVirtualList(listItemWeWant) {
    getToVirtualListItem();
    function getToVirtualListItem() {
      listItemWeWant.isDisplayed().then( (result) => { // failing this, else condition never takes effect
        if (result === true) { // if condition works fine if the item is in the the 10-item list
          waitUntilScrolledToSelectorWithMouseMove(listItemWeWant);
        } else { // it never falls into this else statement
          goToTheEndOfTheViewableList();
          waitUntilScrolledToSelectorWithMouseMove(listItemWeWant);
          console.log('went to the end of the list');
        }
      }).catch( (e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
    }
    async function goToTheEndOfTheViewableList() { // this function never runs. What it does is, click on the virtual list and hold down arrow button.... Maybe there is a better way to do this
      await element(by.tagName('virtual-scroll')).click();
      await browser.driver.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.ARROW_DOWN);
      await browser.sleep(5000); 
      await browser.driver.actions().keyUp(protractor.Key.ARROW_DOWN);
    }
    function waitUntilScrolledToSelectorWithMouseMove (elementSelector: ElementFinder): Promise <{}> {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        browser.driver.wait(() => {
          return browser.driver.actions().mouseMove(elementSelector).perform(); // here is the key line, the rest is a custom promise wrapper
        }, 20000).then( () => {
          resolve(); // resolve the promise d
        }).catch( (e) => {
          console.log('promise not successful: error out');
          reject();
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic page, this simulates pagedown

```
this.scrollTillEnd = function () {
this.woningCount.getText().then(function(woningCount) {
woningCount = woningCount.match(/[0-9]+/g);
var scrollCount = woningCount[0]/15; // each scroll displays 15 items. This is to scroll down till all wonings are displayed
for(i=0; i < scrollCount + 1 ; i++){
        browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)').then(function(){
browser.sleep(2000);
});
            }
    }); 
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this one.
Here's the code for selecting a list element in a virtual list of many elments.

```js
  waitUntilScrolledToSelectorInAVirtualList(listItemWeWantAll: ElementArrayFinder) {
    let recursionCounter = 0;
    const recursionLimit = 1000;
    const focusOnVirtualScrollList = element(by.tagName('virtual-scroll'));
    getToVirtualListItem();
    function getToVirtualListItem() {
      listItemWeWantAll.count().then((result) => {   // get the count of the item, flatten with then...
        if (result >= 1) { // if an element is found
          waitUntilScrolledToSelectorWithMouseMove(listItemWeWantAll.first()); // scroll to the item we want in the list
        } else {
          focusOnVirtualScrollList.click().then(() => {
            browser.driver.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ARROW_DOWN).perform().then(() => {
              recursionCounter++;
              if (recursionCounter > recursionLimit) {
                try {
                  throw new Error('the item does not exist in this list');
                } catch (e) {
                  console.log(e);
                }
              }
              getToVirtualListItem(); // recursive function!
            });
          });
        }
      }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
    }
    function waitUntilScrolledToSelectorWithMouseMove (elementSelector: ElementFinder): Promise <{}> {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        browser.driver.wait(() => {
          return browser.driver.actions().mouseMove(elementSelector).perform();
        }, 20000).then( () => {
          resolve(); // resolve the promise d
        }).catch( (e) => {
          console.log('waitUntilScrolledToSelectorWithMouseMove promise not successful: error out');
          reject();
        });
      });
    }
  }
```